# Why is there no change in my structure? (linked list)

Tags: c

Note the insert_beg function, I have passed the struct address to function and with that I have made operation (insertion at the beginning),so when I traverse the list. Its not getting updated. and If I change the function's (insert_beg) return type to struct node* and assign it to the start(inside main). It's getting reflected. 
Question is, Even though I have passed the start's address to function (call by reference) why is it not getting reflected in the first place?

P.S: I'm new to pointers and structs, Help me out! Thanks!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *link;
};

//Operations
void traverse(struct node *START);
struct node* search(struct node *START,int);
void insert_beg(struct node *START);

int main(){

    struct node *start;
    start = NULL;

    int choice = 1;
    while(choice){
        printf("\n\n****Linked List****\n");
        printf("1.Create Node\n2.Traverse LL\n3.Search\n4.Insert At Beginning\nEnter Your Choice : ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:{
                //create node
                struct node *new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                printf("Enter Data : ");
                scanf("%d",&new_node->val);
                new_node->link = NULL;

                if(start == NULL){
                    //This means that the linked list is empty
                    start = new_node;
                }else{
                    //This means the the ll has more than 1 node
                    struct node *iter = start;
                    while(iter->link != NULL){
                        iter = iter->link;
                    }
                    //iter points to the last node now
                    iter->link = new_node;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                //Traverse
                traverse(start);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                printf("\nEnter the data to be searched : ");
                int data;
                scanf("%d",&data);
                struct node *pos = search(start,data);
                if(pos != NULL)
                    printf("Data : %d is present | Address : %p",pos->val,pos->link);
                else
                    printf("-1");
                break;
            }
            //Insertion
            case 4:{
                //1.Insert Beginning
                insert_beg(start);
               //start = insert_beg(start);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                choice = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    return 7;
}

void insert_beg(struct node *START){
    struct node *new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the data to be stored : ");
    scanf("%d",&new_node->val);
    new_node->link = START;
    START = new_node;
    // return START;
}


void traverse(struct node *START){
    struct node* iter = START;
    int node_count = 0;
    while(iter != NULL){
        printf("Data : %d | Address : %p\n",iter->val,iter);
        iter = iter->link;
        node_count++;
        }
    printf("LL has %d node(s)",node_count);
}

struct node* search(struct node *START,int data){
    struct node* pos = NULL;
    struct node* iter = START;
    if(START != NULL){
    while(iter->link != NULL){
        if(data == iter->val){
            pos = iter;
            break;
        }
        else
            iter = iter->link;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to debug a program

Comment: In C arguments to functions are passed by value. That means the value is copied into the local argument variable of the functions. Changing the argument (assigning to it) will only change the local copy, not the original. Either return the new values (as you know works) or do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: @OldProgrammer There's no compilation error here

Comment: "There's no compilation error here" - Ok?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So the struct * which I'm passing to the function is call by reference?

Comment: @klutt So the struct * which I'm passing to the function is call by reference?

Comment: No, you pass the pointer by value. If you use `void insert_beg(struct node **START);` and `insert_beg(&start);` you would be emulating pass by reference. Please do some searching about the issue.

Comment: Google "c pointer tutorial" or something. You need to learn the basics.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm new to C, Thanks for your info!!

Answer (score 0):

The following changes should correct the problem.

The following passes the address of the head of the list (start) so the contents of the head of the list can be modified.

I also included appropriate error checking

in the prototypes replace:

```
void insert_beg(struct node *START);
```

with:

```
void insert_beg(struct node **START);
```

replace the `insert_beg()` function with the following:

```
void insert_beg(struct node **START)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if( !new_node )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        // free all allocated memory, then
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Enter the data to be stored : ");
    if( scanf("%d",&new_node->val) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for data failed\n" );
        free( new_node );
    }

    if( !(*START)  )
    { // list is empty
        *START = new_node;
        new_node->link = NULL;
    }

    else
    {  // list already contains (at least) one node
        new_node->link = *START;
        *START = new_node;
    }
    // return START;
}
```

When calling `insert_beg()`  use the following statement:

```
insert_beg(&start);
```

Notice, the parameter is the address of the head of the list, not the contents of the head of the list